# Java SQL - Not Properly reading UserInput (username and password)

Tags: java, mysql

We're apparently stuck doing the login program, because it doesn't read the user name and password. It runs, even though the username and password isn't correct.

EXPERIMENTAL WORKING CODE (logs in even if the login details are incorrect):

```
JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Log-In");
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {



            Connection conn;
            java.sql.PreparedStatement ps;

              try{
                  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tupaness","ivanaldwin","frankscanteen");
                  Statement mystmt = conn.createStatement();
                  ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM 'admin' WHERE 'uname' = ? AND 'pass' = ?");


                  String user = uname.getText();   // Collecting the input
                   char[] password = pass.getPassword(); // Collecting the input
                   String pwd = String.valueOf(pass);  // converting from array to string
                   if(validate_login(user,pwd)){

                 /* ps.setString(1, uname.getText());
                  ps.setString(2, String.valueOf(pass.getPassword()));
                  ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();



                  if(result.next()){
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Success");

                      TupanessHome th = new TupanessHome();
                  }
                  */
                   }
                }catch(Exception e) {
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An Error has been Detected: \n" + e);
                }TupanessHome th = new TupanessHome();
        }

        private boolean validate_login(String user, String pwd) {

            try{           
                   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  // MySQL database connection
                   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tupaness","ivanaldwin","frankscanteen");     
                   PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from admin where uname=? and pass=?");
                   pst.setString(1, user); 
                   pst.setString(2, pwd);
                   ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();                        
                   if(rs.next()){            
                       return true;                
                   }
                   else
                       return false;            
               }
               catch(Exception e){
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   return false;
               }       



        }
    });
    btnLogin.setBounds(65, 117, 89, 23);
    login.getContentPane().add(btnLogin);
```

SHOULD-BE CODE (cant work this, says we have some kind of syntax error)

```
    JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Log-In");
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Connection conn;
            java.sql.PreparedStatement ps;

              try{
                  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tupaness","ivanaldwin","frankscanteen");
                  ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM 'admin' WHERE 'uname' = ? AND 'pass' = ?");
                  ps.setString(1, uname.getText());
                  ps.setString(2, String.valueOf(pass.getPassword()));
                  ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

                  if(result.next()){
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Success");

                      TupanessHome th = new TupanessHome();
                  }

                }catch(Exception e) {
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An Error has been Detected: \n" + e);
                }
        }
    });
    btnLogin.setBounds(65, 117, 89, 23);
    login.getContentPane().add(btnLogin);
```

EDIT

We managed to fix the error in the column, but it still wont login

```
  ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE 'uname' = ? AND 'pass' = ?");
```

(The statement came from the 'SHOULD BE CODE')

Comment: You have quotes around the table and column names in your `SELECT` query.  There are probably other things wrongs too, but start by fixing the query.

Comment: Okay we will start locating those errors, thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"SELECT * FROM 'admin' WHERE 'uname' = ? AND 'pass' = ?"
```

Should be

```
"SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `uname` = ? AND `pass` = ?"
```

Or even

```
"SELECT * FROM admin WHERE uname = ? AND pass = ?"
```

Comment: IT FINALLY WORKED THANK YOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOU